# Duplicate Records on Inner Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm migrating a project that was pulling data from a MySQL database to a SQL database. The problem is that i'm running into duplicate records that I was able to quickly resolve when I was using a MySQL database. SQL on the other hand is giving me issues.

I have two tables: AllOrderData and CallSettings

Both tables have a column labeled OrderNumber. Sometimes there are multiple records on both tables with the same OrderNumber. I only need to display one record in these situations.

This is what i have now:

```
$dt = $_GET ["dt"];

$sql = "SELECT
  A.OrderNumber,
  A.DetailShipDate,
  A.ETC,
    C.OrderNumber,
    C.ETC
FROM AllOrderData A
INNER JOIN CallSettings C ON A.OrderNumber = C.OrderNumber
WHERE A.DetailShipDate = '$dt'";
```

I tried to add DISTINCT and also GROUP BY but I've read they're used for distinct rows and it's just not working.

When I was using MySQL, I had all the data in one table. Unfortunately, that's not an option anymore but the query was very simple:

```
$sql_string = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE DetailShipDate='$dt' group by Order_Number
```

I tried the following:

```
 $sql = "SELECT x.OrderNumber,
                x.EnteredBy,
                x.Order_Number,
                x.Contact_Name
   FROM (SELECT A.OrderNumber,
                A.EnteredBy,
                C.Order_Number,
                C.Contact_Name
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY A.OrderNumber
                                   ORDER BY C.Order_Number) rn
                FROM AllOrderData A
                     INNER JOIN CallSettings C
                                ON A.OrderNumber = C.Order_Number
                WHERE A.DetailShipDate = '$dt') x
   WHERE x.rn = 1;";
```

And Got this error:

Error in query preparation/execution. Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 42000 [SQLSTATE] => 42000 [1] => 102 [code] => 102 [2] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. [message] => [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '('. ) )

Comment: your query is wrong  ... missing comma between colums ...

Comment: what do you mean migrate form MySQL to SQL?  What flavor of SQL is your target?

Comment: The missing commas was just a typo. The data was previously hosted on a MySQL database but now its hosted on a SQL database.

Comment: Yes, SQL Server. The query returns all records but its filled with duplicate records. I just want to get rid of the duplicates. Let's not focus on the stuff that doesn't matter.

Comment: There is no significant difference between MySQL and MSSQL in this regard; it is the change in table structure that is the source of your problem. You say you only need one record, but the question becomes _which_ record. Are CallSettings records with the same OrderNumber identical to each other?

Comment: @Uueerdo That is incorrect. OPs query of `SELECT * FROM orders WHERE DetailShipDate='$dt' GROUP BY Order_Num` will error in sql server, but run just fine in MySQL returning a single row for each `Order_Number` (before 5.7, after 5.7 would require a settings change to not error). I agree though that the question "Which record" needs to be asked. OP's Mysql query (though it would run) is garbag-y as it would pick a random value if multiple values were present in a field besides `Order_Number`.

Comment: @JNevill Ah, yeah, I completely overlooked the `GROUP BY` (ab)use.

Comment: @JD6969 You absolutely need to decide how to aggregate any field that has differing data for each `Order_Number`. Like `Max(DetailShipDate) AS DetailShipDate` for any remaining field that is the same for each record, you can just add that to your GROUP BY like `GROUP BY Order_Number, SomeOtherField`. The MySQL way of doing this (Which produces bad results, in my opinion) isn't going to work in sql server.

Comment: (ab)use... kindred spirits here, me and you. I was so happy when 5.7 hit and that "feature" was buried in the settings.

Comment: Lets say AllOrderData and CallSettings both have 3 records with the same OrderNumber, I only want it to show 1 record AND it doesnt matter which one. It can be any of the 3. All 3 will have the same OrderNumer and DetailShipDate but there are 20 other columns where the data will be different. This is for one of the many different user views on the web app.

Comment: You miss a `,` after `C.Contact_Name`...

Comment: @stickybit you're right. It works but i'm missing some records...:(

Comment: So *this* question is answered then, I guess.

Comment: No because there are other records with unique order numbers that are not listed. It should show a total of 5 records, all with unique order numbers, but only 3 are listed.

Comment: I marked your post as an answer but again, it still doesn't work 100 percent.

Comment: "I only want it to show 1 record AND it doesnt matter which one" The random `ROW_NUMBER()` generation is truly the only way to tell an RDBMS to do this. Why even show the other 20 columns though. It's like saying "And here's some random selections from this order..." The alternative to the `ROW_NUMBER()` subquery is to wrap each of those other 20 columns in `Max()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`. Partition and order by the order number.

```
SELECT x.ordernumber,
       x.detailshipdate,
       x.etc,
       x.ordernumber,
       x.etc
       FROM (SELECT a.ordernumber,
                    a.detailshipdate,
                    a.etc,
                    c.ordernumber,
                    c.etc,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY c.ordernumber
                                       ORDER BY c.ordernumber) rn
                    FROM allorderdata a
                         INNER JOIN callsettings c
                                    ON a.ordernumber = c.ordernumber
                    WHERE a.detailshipdate = ?) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

Comment: What is the x in this line? WHERE a.detailshipdate = '$dt') x

Comment: @JD6969: An alias for the derived table.